# Is there another way to find projection a point on a line by using TikZ without using 3dtools?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Let `S.ABCD` be a pyramid, `ABCD` is a square, `SA` perpendicular to the plane `(ABCD)`; `P` is projection of `A` on `SC`, `P` is projection of `A` on `SD`.
Based on [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470881/is-there-a-command-to-find-coordinates-of-projection-of-a-point-on-a-line-in-3d), I tried

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\tikzset{projection of point/.style args={(#1,#2,#3) on line through (#4,#5,#6)
        and (#7,#8,#9)}{%
        /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\myprefactor}{((#1-#4)*(#7-#4)+(#2-#5)*(#8-#5)+(#3-#6)*(#9-#6))/((#7-#4)*(#7-#4)+(#8-#5)*(#8-#5)+(#9-#6)*(#9-#6))},
        insert path={%
            ({#4+\myprefactor*(#7-#4)},{#5+\myprefactor*(#8-#5)},{#6+\myprefactor*(#9-#6)})}
}}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
    %\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{100}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.5]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\a{4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\h{4}
        
        % definitions
        \path
        coordinate(A) at (0,0,0)
        coordinate (B) at (\a,0,0)
        coordinate (C) at (\a,\b,0) 
        
        coordinate (D) at (0,\b,0)                          
        coordinate (S) at (0,0,\h)                
        %coordinate (E) at ($(B)!0.5!(S)$)
        coordinate (J) at ($(B)!(A)!(S)$);
        \path[projection of point={(0,0,0) on line through (\a,\b,0) and (0,0,\a)}]
        coordinate[label=above right:$P$] (P)
        [projection of point={(0,0,0) on line through (0,\b,0) and (0,0,\a)}]
        coordinate[label=above right:$Q$] (Q)
        ;
        \draw[dashed,thick]
        (A) -- (B)  (A) -- (C)  (D)--(A) (S) -- (A) ;
        \draw[thick]
        (S) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle (S) -- (C) ;
        %\draw[red, thick, dashed]  (A)-- ($(B)!(A)!(S)$);
        \draw[red, thick, dashed]  (A)-- (P) (A)-- (Q) ;
        \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/left,C/below,S/above,D/right}
        {
            \fill (\point) circle (.8pt);
            \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there  another way to find projection a point on a line by using TikZ without using 3dtools? and draw the circle passing three points `C, D, P`.

[image]

Comment: What don't you like about 3D tools? You seem to be asking how to do something of type X without using tools designed for doing things of type X. If you just didn't like `tikz-3dplot` it would be different ....

Answer (score 0):

I use Maple to find coordinates of two points `P` and `Q`. About the circle `CDP`, I use 3dtools! Therefore, I don't add that code.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\a{4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\h{4}
        
        % definitions
        \path
        coordinate(A) at (0,0,0)
        coordinate (B) at (\a,0,0)
        coordinate (C) at (\a,\b,0) 
        
        coordinate (D) at (0,\b,0)                          
        coordinate (S) at (0,0,\h)                
    ({\h*\h*\a/(\a*\a +\b*\b + \h*\h)}, {\h*\h*\b/(\a*\a +\b*\b + \h*\h)}, {\h*(\a*\a +\b*\b)/(\a*\a +\b*\b + \h*\h)}) coordinate (P)
(0, {\h*\h*\b/(\b*\b + \h*\h)}, {\h*\b*\b/(\b*\b + \h*\h)}) coordinate (Q)
        ;
        \draw[dashed,thick]
        (A) -- (B)  (A) -- (C)  (D)--(A) (S) -- (A) ;
        \draw[thick]
        (S) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle (S) -- (C) ;
        \draw[red, thick, dashed]  (A)-- (P) (A)-- (Q) ;
        \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/left,C/below,S/above,D/right,P/right,Q/right}
        {
            \fill (\point) circle (.8pt);
            \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So 3dtools is software of some kind?

Comment: https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614030/how-to-draw-circle-passing-through-three-points-in-3d/614272#614272