# How can you make animated objects on LaTeX and what programs do you have to use?

Tags: animations

My primary question is that is it possible to make animated objects on LaTeX and what programs do you have to use if this is actually possible?

Comment: There are several options. 1. The `animate` package. 2. `beamer` allows you to animate. 3. The latest `tikz` version has animation facilities. 4. You can use [convert to create animated gifs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799). 5. You can [create mp4 files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462207/121799).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some of the options that I am aware of (not an exhaustive list):

1. The [`animate` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate?lang=en) allows you to produce animations.
2. [`beamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer?lang=en) allows you to animate stuff.
3. The latest [`tikz/pgf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) version has animation facilities. See the answers of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469409/121799) for details.
4. You can [use `convert` to create animated gifs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799). Many of the animated gifs that you can find on this site are produced that way.
5. You can [create `mp4` files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462207/121799). This is particularly useful if you want to produce "movies" like [this one](https://github.com/samcarter/Extravanganza2018). Unfortunately, one cannot upload `mp4` files here AFAIK.