# Is it possible to introduce animation in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

Is it possible to animate a tikz diagram.

For instance, a line and a circle , can form a static pendulum.

Will it be possible to add oscillation to the same.

Comment: Sure. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472050/121799) you can find an incomplete list of options. If you tell us which output format you are looking for, you will make it easier to answer this question.