# Change beamer slide title in overlay

Tags: beamer, overlays

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red, very thick](0, 0) -- (3, 0);
    \onslide<1>{
      \draw(-1, 1) -- (2, 1);
    }
    \onslide<2>{
      \draw(-2, 2) -- (1, 2);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have successfully developed an animation using `\onslide<>`:

[image]

However, I would also like to change the slide title when running through the animation. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{Some title}
\frametitle<2>{Another title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red, very thick](0, 0) -- (3, 0);
    \onslide<1>{
      \draw(-1, 1) -- (2, 1);
    }
    \onslide<2>{
      \draw(-2, 2) -- (1, 2);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The perhaps simplest option I see is to use an `overlay` picture in the case the of titles which occupy different amounts of vertical space.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<1>{Some title}
\frametitle<2>{Another title which is very very long and spans two lines
or even more}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,shift={([yshift=-1cm]current page.center)}]
    \draw[red, very thick](0, 0) -- (3, 0);
    \onslide<1>{
      \draw(-1, 1) -- (2, 1);
    }
    \onslide<2>{
      \draw(-2, 2) -- (1, 2);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An IMHO better solution would be to [write the data to the `aux` file and restore it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541958/194703). This also allows you to work with `\pause` in `tikzpicture`s without inducing jumps, BTW. However, you do not seem to be interested in such solutions (which is perfectly fine, of course), which is why I am not spelling this out here.

Comment: Thanks! There is a problem though when one of the titles occupies two lines