# Plot Dini's surface

Tags: pgfplots, pstricks, plot, tikz-3dplot

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_surface), the Dini's surface is described by the following parametric equations:

```
x = a \cos u \sin v
y = a \sin u \sin v
z = a (\cos v + \ln\tan v/2) + bu
```

So, I'd like to plot the surface and obtain a result similar to the one below ([got from here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~ddumas/teaching/2007/spring/math18/)) to be used on a book cover (this is why I'd like to do it by myself instead of using the one from link):

[image]

I mean, the same shape, not necessarily the same coloring.

I tried the following code but far away from the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
  samples=20,
  domain=0:14*pi,y domain=0:2,
  z buffer=sort]
  ({ 2 *cos(x) * sin(y)}, {2*sin(x) * sin(y)}, {2*(cos(y)+ln(tan(y/2))) + 0.15*x});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to reproduce the surface? It could be with different approach, not only `pgfplots`.

---

**Edit:** After using accepted solution below, I decided to edit here to show the result I got. Also, I searched for the colors in color map Pastel.

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    view={15}{10},
    hide axis,
    width=12cm,height=6cm,
    mesh/interior colormap=
      {pastel}{
      rgb255(0.00cm)=(194,120,239);
      rgb255(0.08cm)=(206,149,243);
      rgb255(0.17cm)=(220,165,196);
      rgb255(0.25cm)=(231,178,165);
      rgb255(0.33cm)=(238,194,152);
      rgb255(0.42cm)=(243,214,149);
      rgb255(0.50cm)=(245,232,151);
      rgb255(0.58cm)=(241,243,161);
      rgb255(0.67cm)=(227,240,185);
      rgb255(0.75cm)=(196,226,218);
      rgb255(0.83cm)=(151,204,243);
      rgb255(0.92cm)=(109,180,236);
      },
    colormap/cool,
    trig format plots=rad,
    point meta={z*z+y*y-0.3*z},
  ]
  \addplot3[
    surf,
    %shader=faceted,
    faceted color=black!80,
    %faceted color=mapped color!50,
    line width=0.1pt,
    samples=150, samples y=20,
    domain=1.5*pi:6.5*pi, y domain=0.02*pi:0.12*pi,
    z buffer=sort
  ]
  (
  {2*(cos(y)+ln(tan(y/2))) + 0.6*x},
  {2 *cos(x) * sin(y)},
  {-2*sin(x) * sin(y)} 
  );
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `trig format plots=rad` is a minor step in the right direction, I think. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, thanks. I never heard about it. Let me search for.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, please, see the edited post.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, and maybe some one knows the correct palette. Done.

Comment: Looks great!!!!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wikipedia could be right. Most importantly, you need to add `trig format plots=rad`. Then you might reorder the axes directions, change the parameters and plot ranges, add different colormaps for the interior and outerior, add a `point meta`, and so on. This allows you to qualitatively reproduce their result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={10}{10},hide axis,
 width=12cm,height=6cm,
 colormap={bluegray}{color=(blue) color=(gray!20)},
 mesh/interior colormap={orangered}{color=(red) color=(orange)},
 trig format plots=rad,point meta={z*z+y*y-0.3*z}]
  \addplot3[surf,%shader=flat,
  samples=201,samples y=25,
  domain=1.5*pi:6.5*pi,y domain=0.02*pi:0.12*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  ({2*(cos(y)+ln(tan(y/2))) + 0.6*x},{2 *cos(x) * sin(y)}, {-2*sin(x) * sin(y)} 
  );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you want to see the trumpet shape more pronounced,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={12}{10},hide axis,
 width=16cm,height=9cm,
 colormap={blueyellow}{color=(blue) color=(yellow)},
 mesh/interior colormap={orangeyellow}{color=(red) color=(yellow)},
 trig format plots=rad,point meta={z*z+y*y-0.5*z}]
  \addplot3[surf,%shader=flat,
  samples=101,samples y=15,
  domain=1.5*pi:6.5*pi,y domain=0.02*pi:0.48*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  ({2*(cos(y)+ln(tan(y/2))) + 0.7*x},{2 *cos(x) * sin(y)}, {-2*sin(x) * sin(y)} 
  );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with the color map `Sigur`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={12}{10},hide axis,
 width=16cm,height=9cm,
 colormap={Sigur inv}{rgb255(0cm)=(106,172,233); rgb255(1cm)=(241,238,141); rgb255(2cm)=(181,99,233)},
 mesh/interior colormap={Sigur}{rgb255(0cm)=(181,99,233); rgb255(1cm)=(241,238,141); rgb255(2cm)=(106,172,233)},
 trig format plots=rad,point meta={z*z+y*y-0.5*z}]
  \addplot3[surf,%shader=flat,
  samples=101,samples y=15,faceted color=blue!40!mapped color,
  domain=1.5*pi:6.5*pi,y domain=0.02*pi:0.48*pi,
  z buffer=sort,line width=0.01pt]
  ({2*(cos(y)+ln(tan(y/2))) + 0.7*x},{2 *cos(x) * sin(y)}, {-2*sin(x) * sin(y)} 
  );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

All of these can be animated in the usual way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,0.1,...,1.9}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={12}{10},hide axis,
 width=16cm,height=9cm,
 colormap={Sigur inv}{rgb255(0cm)=(106,172,233); rgb255(1cm)=(241,238,141); rgb255(2cm)=(181,99,233)},
 mesh/interior colormap={Sigur}{rgb255(0cm)=(181,99,233); rgb255(1cm)=(241,238,141); rgb255(2cm)=(106,172,233)},
 trig format plots=rad,point meta={z*z+y*y-0.5*z}]
  \addplot3[surf,%shader=flat,
  samples=101,samples y=15,faceted color=blue!40!mapped color,
  domain={(1+\X)*pi}:{(6+\X)*pi},y domain=0.02*pi:0.48*pi,
  z buffer=sort,line width=0.01pt]
  ({2*(cos(y)+ln(tan(y/2))) + 0.7*x},{2 *cos(x) * sin(y)}, {-2*sin(x) * sin(y)} 
  );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing all examples, specially the animated one.

Comment: I'll try to make it faster with more frames, and maybe smaller size to upload to the webpage.

Comment: How did you do the gif?

Comment: @Sigur I think you should try mp3, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462207/194703. The only reason I used gif here is that one cannot upload mp3 on this site. But if you have your own web site, mp3 might be better. The gif was created with `convert -density 180 -delay 34 -loop 0 -alpha remove <file>.pdf ani.gif`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/194703.

Comment: It took 84s to compile. But nice!

Comment: @Sigur You could ask for the code for the animation in the other answer and then compare performances.... ;-) (But such comparisons are never entirely fair, different codes have different numbers of plot points, different flexibility, and so on. With pgfplots you pay a price for being able to adjust the `point meta` at will, change the line colors along the path, and so on and so forth.)

Comment: I created a reversed gif with `convert surface.gif -coalesce   -duplicate 1,-2-1 -quiet -layers OptimizePlus -loop 0 ssurface.gif`

Comment: @Sigur You could also do `\foreach \X in {2,1.9,...,0.1}` ... ;-)

Comment: Yes, but `convert` is faster in this case... :-)

Comment: @sigur, OK, you win. An mp3 can be played backwards, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: mp4 you mean...

Comment: @Sigur Yes, that's right. I always forget that.

Comment: Very well done!

Answer (score 16):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\def\A{3.0}
\def\B{0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.2,13)
\psset[pst-solides3d]{viewpoint=20 -20 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=15,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\defFunction[algebraic]{shell}(u,v)%
   {\A*cos(u)*sin(v)}%
   {\A*sin(u)*sin(v)}%
   {\A*(cos(v)+ln(tan(v/2))) + \B*u}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree, 
  linecolor={[cmyk]{1,0,1,0.5}}, 
  base=0 pi 8 mul  0.1 2, fillcolor=yellow!50,
  incolor=green!50, function=shell, linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,ngrid=100 50]%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image][image][image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\def\A{3.0}
\def\B{0.5}
\multido{\iA=0+20}{18}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.2,13)
\psset[pst-solides3d]{viewpoint=20 \iA\space 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=15,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\defFunction[algebraic]{shell}(u,v)%
   {\A*cos(u)*sin(v)}%
   {\A*sin(u)*sin(v)}%
   {\A*(cos(v)+ln(tan(v/2))) + \B*u}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree, 
  linecolor={[cmyk]{1,0,1,0.5}}, 
  base=0 pi 8 mul  0.1 2, fillcolor=yellow!50,
  incolor=green!50, function=shell, linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,ngrid=100 50]%
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

And then use `convert` from ImageMagick:

```
convert -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 -scale 300 -alpha remove test.pdf test.gif
```

The last animation has a fixed lightsource at `10 10 10`

Comment: Beautiful color map.

Comment: Please, could you post code for animation also?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Do you convert from dvi to pdf directly? Thanks so much.

Comment: I am running `xelatex`, which uses `xdvipdfmx` in the background and the `pdf`  is the default output format

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use some gradient in filling colors?

Comment: I observed that the `viewpoint` are changing to give the movement illusion. How to make `lightsrc` constant? I mean, with the movement I'd like to see the shadow at same region like the light source was not moving.

Comment: for example: `lightsrc=10 10 10 rtp2xyz` for a light source position at r=10, phi=10degrees, theta=10 degrees. Alternatively you can use `lightsrc=10 9 8'  for x=10, y=9, x=8

Comment: What I'd like to obtain is: the source light at same position when creating another pages, that is, the light does not turn rotate witht he surface, so the shadow would be always as the same region of space.

Comment: The _first_ animation has a fixed region of the shadow.

Comment: So, just use the 1st code within the animation code, right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, that's correct