# Export beamer presentation to mp4

Tags: beamer, export, video

Is there any way to convert latex generated presentations to mp4 video? The time for slides need not be same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/663179/convert-pdf-presentation-to-video

Comment: How about [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462206/194703)? It also works for beamer presentations. And you can create movies like [this one](https://vimeo.com/305374856).