# how to add our voice to slides in a presentation?

Tags: texmaker, slideshow

I made my slides with latex texmaker for a seminar. Now I have to do online presentation. how I can put my voice on slides?

Comment: You can use the methods described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462207).

Comment: I want to talk on each page. how I can record my voice? it was not clear to me?

Comment: You can use your microphone on the computer (provided you have one). Note that many just share their screen for presentations, and talk in real time. Of course, this can be recorded. However, none of this is a LaTeX question, there might be sites specifically for this.